# PyGame: Collision Detection With Block

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame

In a platformer I am making I have got generated terrain but no collision. Here is the code I have tried to use to check for the collision:

```
def player_move(self):

    self.player.rect.x += self.player.velX
    self.check_collision(self.player, self.player.velX, 0)
    self.player.rect.y += self.player.velY
    self.check_collision(self.player, 0, self.player.velY)

def check_collision(self, sprite, x_vel, y_vel):
    # for every tile in Background.levelStructure, check for collision
    for block in self.moon.get_surrounding_blocks(sprite):
        if block is not None:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite, block):
                # we've collided! now we must move the collided sprite a step back
                if x_vel < 0:
                    sprite.rect.x = block.rect.x + block.rect.w

                if x_vel > 0:
                    sprite.rect.x = block.rect.x - sprite.rect.w

                if y_vel < 0:
                    sprite.rect.y = block.rect.y + block.rect.h
```

And then I have the code for the level generation too if this will help out:

```
import pygame, random

# Level
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('data/images/block.png')

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def render(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)



class Background():

    def __init__(self):
        self.bg_image = pygame.image.load('data/images/background.jpg')


        # create a 2-dimensional array (etc. tile[x][y]) for holding the level structure
        self.levelStructure = [[None for i in range(50)] for i in range(50)]

        # generate level on initialization
        self.generateLevel()

    def generateLevel(self):
        # fill self.levelStructure with tiles
        for x in range(20):
            for y in range(9):
                if y < 11:
                    # make top space for the player to be
                    continue

                tempBlock = Block(x*40, y*40)

                # add block to both and self.levelStructure
                self.levelStructure[x][y] = tempBlock

        # generate some random terrain
        for x in range(25):
            # get a random height
            height = random.randint(2, 5)

            for y in range(height):
                y += 15
                tempBlock = Block(x*40, (y-height)*40)
                self.levelStructure[x][y-height] = tempBlock

    def get_surrounding_blocks(self, sprite):
        # calculate the grid position of the sprite
        sprite_x = sprite.rect.x // 40
        sprite_y = sprite.rect.y // 40

        # generate a list of surrounding sprites
        blocks = []
        for x in range(-2, 2+1):
            for y in range(-2, 2+1):
                blocks.append(self.levelStructure[sprite_x + x][sprite_y + y])

        return blocks

    def render(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.bg_image, (0, 0))

        # also draw the blocks we created
        for x in range(22):
            for y in range(15):
                block = self.levelStructure[x][y]

                # check if there is a block, or if the grid is empty
                if block is not None:
                    block.render(surface)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems.

Firstly, you never tell the velocity to change...  You probably want it to stop, or reverse when you hit a block.

Secondly, you are iterating through all the blocks twice, once for checking X axis, once for Y.  For large or complex maps, this will make it twice as slow.

I'd also advise against using the `collide_rect` function to test for collisions in this instance, unless you're very sure that velocity cannot be higher than the total size of a block (or the sprite).  If you're moving 71px a frame, but the block size is 20px wide, and your player is only 50px wide, you can jump right past a block without bumping into it at all!

One thing to be very careful of, is that you're moving the object, and then checking for collisions.  This is likely to cause problems, as you then have to move it back to where it was before.

I'd advise changing your structure to something like:

```
def player_move(self):

    # create some local vars for ease of reading...
    x = self.player.rect.x
    x_next = x + self.player.velX

    y = self.player.rect.y
    y_next = y + self.player.vely

    w = self.player.rect.w
    h = self.player.rect.h

    # has a collision happened?
    hitX = False
    hitY = False

    for block in self.moon.get_surrounding_blocks(self.player):

        # empty blocks are 'None' in this map system...
        if not block:
            continue

        if self.player.velX > 0:  # moving right
            if x + w < block.x and x_next + w >= block.x:
                # collision!
                x_next =  block.x - w
                hitX = True
        elif self.player.velX < 0: # moving left
            if x > block.x + block.w and x_next > block.x + block.w:
                # collision!
                x_next = block.x + block.w
                hitX = True

         if self.player.velY...... # do the same for Y axis...

    # now update rect to have the new collision fixed positions:

    self.player.rect.x = x_next
    self.player.rect.y = y_next

    # and if there was a collision, fix the velocity.

    if hitX:
        self.velX = 0  # or 0 - velX to bounce instead of stop
    if hitY:
        self.velY = 0  # or 0 - velY to bounce instead of stop
```

Hopefully this helps to move things in the right direction...

One other thought, when I was writing a platform engine some years ago, I remember I had some issues at one stage with player objects hitting blocks, stopping, but then starting again.  In the end, it was off-by-one errors somewhere in the code.  It may be worth adding a bunch of debugging printing (best to use the 'logging' package...) and then slowing down your frame rate a lot, so you can see exactly what happens.

Good luck!  Writing games is a lot of fun, but can be very frustrating at times too.

Comment: Thank you so much. Collisions is the one thing I really struggle on and I think you have now helped me a bunch! I am defitely going to give this a try. Also what you said is very true making games is fun but frustrating. Thank you again.

Comment: Tried the code and fixed a few parts of it that needed to be toggled, and I run the program then it says: Global name sprite is not defined. The error occurs here: `for block in self.moon.get_surrounding_blocks(sprite):`

Comment: Ah, oops. Yes, I'd just copied your '`for block in...`' line from your previous version.  I've replaced it now with `self.player`, which was what was getting sent to that function.

Comment: Ok thank you wondered why it didnt work. Thats all. Thanks again.

Comment: Right that has fixed that now the game will load up but there is an attribute error saying: 'if y > block.y + block.h and y_next > block.y + block.h:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'y''

Comment: GhostFrag1 - I think you need some more python experience in general... that error means that it's looking for an attribute called 'y' on a none object.  Add a simple `if block:` into the loop... (I'll update the code I posted for completeness' sake, but that kind of error is trivial to diagnose.)  The code I posted was an example of the kind of approach I'd suggest, rather than a full finished algorithm.  I'd encourage you to get more basic python experience, while not giving up on your game.

Comment: Ok I will. But most errors I come across I have not seen before so I don't know much about them.

Comment: That's fine. :-)  It does take a while.  I just don't want you to get discouraged from writing your game.  Following some python tutorials, and getting more familiar with the language in general will help a lot.   Good luck!